# Linux copy multiple files and rename increment fashion

Tags: linux, shell

I have to write a shell script that copies multiple files to a different location and rename the file in incremental format.

Example:

The files will be in the format filename.txt.yyyymmddhhmmss1 . In a single day multiple files created in this pattern..

sample:

```
/dir1
    filename.txt.yyyymmdd1234561
    filename.txt.yyyymmdd2345121
```

it should be copied to another directory `dir2` as below

```
filename.txt.yyyymmdd1234561 --> filename.txt.1
filename.txt.yyyymmdd1234561 --> filename.txt.11
```

If a third file created on same day at different file it should be like `filename.txt.111`

Similarly for files that with 2.

```
filename.txt.yyyymmdd1234562 --> filename.txt.2
filename.txt.yyyymmdd1234562 --> filename.txt.22
```

Is it possible through shell script, I can do the copying and renaming but not in the incremental fashion.

Comment: ??  What do you mean by "for files that with 2".    Are you just discarding all but the last digit from the original filename?  It's not at all clear what you want the new names to be.

Comment: Is the last digit of the original filename the extension you want to keep? Only extended for as many other copies of that extension you have? Is that incrementing format required? Does `cp --backup=numbered` do something you can use instead?